# Removing Section Name in Heading of Reference Page

Tags: biblatex, header-footer

I am using the `\pagestyle{myheadings}` command to put page numbers on my document which does not include the Section Name in the heading.

However, that does not seem to work on the References page of my document which was created using the `\printbibliography` command.

How can I effect a `\pagestyle{myheadings}` command on the contents created by the `\printbibliography` command?

I tried using `\printbibliography[heading=none]` but it also removes the Section Name. What I want is for only the Section Name in heading (left side of a page number) be removed.

The following example illustrates this. This will output a two page document. 1st page contains a page number in the header, but does not include section Name (Bipartite Matching). But on the References page, References is included in the header plus the page numbers... I don't want that..

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage[backend=bibtex8]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{other_bib.bib}

\pagestyle{myheadings}
\begin{document}
\section{Bipartite Matching}

Given a bipartite graph $G=(A \cup B,E)$, a \textit{matching} $M$ in $G$ is a set of pairwise non-adjacent edges such that no edges in $M$ share a common vertex\cite[][pp. 184]{Chartrand05}. 

\newpage
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Try `\printbibliography\pagestyle{empty}`.

Comment: @Sigur, it does not work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The file `biblatex.def` contains all defined headings. All are using `\markboth`. So you can simple redefine the original definition and remove `markboth`:

```
\defbibheading{bibliography}[\refname]{%
  \section*{#1}%
  %\markboth{\MakeUppercase{#1}}{\MakeUppercase{#1}}
}
```

Please note `\section*` hasn't a section number so you will get the last defined section number. I think the more suitable redefinition would be:

```
\defbibheading{bibliography}[\refname]{%
  \section*{#1}%
  \markboth{}{}
}
```

which removes the entry in the heading.